# Java Streams group list entries based on a property but collect a property of object in Map

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

Sorry for the weird title. Basically what I'm trying to do is as follows.
I have a class called Details, let's say.

```
class Detail{
        String title;
        Project project;
}
```

Using Streams, as you can see I'm able to group Detail by their titles. However I want to group Projects inside of those Detail by title, not Detail.

```
List<Detail> results; // not empty    
Map<String, List<Detail>> res = results
                    .stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(Detail::getTitle));
```

Thanks, beforehand

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Map<String, List<Project>> res = results
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Detail::getTitle,
        Collectors.mapping(Detail::getProject, Collectors.toList())));
```